# Magento 2 Admin Orders Date show not actual result

Tags: magento2, orders, filter, order-grid, date

I have Magento 2.4.2-p1 EE.

When i filter orders by dates, example: **Purchase Date: 12/12/2021 - 12/12/2021** [image]

I have result with 777 found orders.

[image]

**But on last page i can see orders with wrong dates for active filters. How fix this?**

[image]

Comment: What's your timezone? I guess it's +4hours to UTC or someting? Do you have different timezones configured for Admin and Frontend?

Comment: @simonthesorcerer i too think problem with timezone. Maybe I'm just in a different time zone and therefore everything is displayed a little incorrectly for me?

Answer (score 0):

**Method to Configure Magento 2 Stores and Time Zones:**

Login to Admin Panel

**Navigate to Stores > Configuration**

From the left side navigation menu, select the **General tab** under the **General menu.**

Here you’ll find the **locale and store information** dropdown menu

.1_General
Expand the locale drop-down option and configure the below settings

2 Stores and Time Zones
Time Zone – Set the time zone of the store

Save the configuration
Navigate to System > Cache Management > Flush Magento Cache and clear the cache